# What is the size limit of a single document stored in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a MongoDB database in Azure (registered under a Cosmos DB account) and I read on [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits) that the size limit per document stored is 2MB. However, when I try to store an image buffer that is around 1.7 MB I get the following error:

```
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057681416Z { MongoError: Message: {"Errors":["Request size is too large"]}
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057757320Z RequestStartTime: 2019-11-01T00:43:13.9695930Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-11-01T00:43:13.9995776Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057768921Z ResponseTime: 2019-11-01T00:43:13.9995776Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-centralus1-fd19.documents.azure.com:14112/apps/0806fa15-6a2d-4127-a73b-b1626ddd8af1/services/5618d8a3-dc06-4e8a-ba18-39d3b0c58add/partitions/d61f7139-78bf-423b-a4d7-747179270393/replicas/132167814077711166p/, LSN: -1, GlobalCommittedLsn: -1, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 410, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 0, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: , UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057779921Z SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057788121Z     at Function.create (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/error.js:44:12)
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057796322Z     at toError (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:150:22)
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057804822Z     at coll.s.topology.insert (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/common_functions.js:266:39)
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057813223Z     at handler (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:1000:24)
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057821223Z     at wireProtocol.(anonymous function) (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:457:5)
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057829423Z     at /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:408:18
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057837624Z     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057845624Z   driver: true,
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057853424Z   name: 'MongoError',
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057861125Z   index: 0,
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057868725Z   code: 16,
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057876326Z   errmsg:
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057886326Z    'Message: {"Errors":["Request size is too large"]}\r\n, RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2019-11-01T00:43:13.9695930Z, RequestEndTime: 2019-11-01T00:43:13.9995776Z,  Number of regions attempted:1\r\nResponseTime: 2019-11-01T00:43:13.9995776Z, LSN: -1, GlobalCommittedLsn: -1, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 410, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 0, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: , UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create\r\n, SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.7.0',
2019-11-01T00:43:14.057902127Z   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Currently, I'm on an `Azure for Students` subscription and I've been using the free tier for all of my resources. I also read in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#storage-and-throughput) on storage and throughput, but I'm not sure what I would have to modify in order to get things working.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: In case you are still interested, Are you wondering about the apparent > 15% (2 - 1.7) / 2 bloat or the max file size?
It certainly makes it challenging to plan your partition keys if you don't know how big an individual doc is going to be when you save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of a document is 2 MB and cannot be increased. In your case you can store the image in blob storage and attach the url as a property to the document you are saving which will save few bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There is encoding that takes place, when storing a document in Cosmos DB. I suspect your binary data, when encoded (expanding its stored size), is going to be the issue pushing your document size well beyond what's expected (and beyond the 2MB size limit).

As @sajeetharan mentioned, there are alternative ways to store your binary data (such as a blob, with only a reference uri in your Cosmos DB document), that will help reduce blob size.

The type of subscription you have has nothing to do with Cosmos DB's document size limits.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-request-limits), Maximum request size is 2MB.

[image]

The total request contains the file size and [common requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers).You could capture the request and check the size of it by using [Fiddler Tool](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: is not the same answer above?