# Azure Data factory Copy data Blob to Cosmos db - need help skipping 2MB files

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Azure Data Factory Copy Activity within a pipeline - I'm copying data from Blob container /jsons in multiple virtual folders/ to Cosmos DB. However, fringe cases exist and cannot be escaped, where files larger than 2MB are placed in the Blob storage. When the copy activity picks them, the transfer /and subsequent pipeline activities/ fail as I hit the 2MB hard limit for CosmosDB.
I have tried setting up a lookup activity / get metadata but can't seem to address properly the relevant (size) property and the output necessary for the delete activity.

Can anyone advise on a an approach on how to handle this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to get the [size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#metadata-options) of files in Get Metadata activity.But please note it is in bytes and only could be applied on the file.

[image]

As i know,no way to avoid 2mb limitation of cosmos db document.You could refer to this case:[What is the size limit of a single document stored in Azure Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58653153/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-single-document-stored-in-azure-cosmos-db)